# How to acess dbRef.$id and dbRef.$ref in mongosh?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell, dbref

Using MongoDB:          6.0.4
Using Mongosh:          1.4.1

I inserted a book and a publisher (dbRef) with mongosh.

```
# insert publisher
publisher_id = ObjectId()
db.publishers.insert_one({
    '_id': publisher_id,
    'title': 'XXX',
    'website': 'https://xxxxxxx.com',
})

# insert books
db.books.insert_one({
    'title': 'Good book',
    'author': 'Someone',
    'publishers': [ 
        {
            '$ref': 'publishers',
            '$id': publisher_id, 
        },
    ], 
})
```

Then run the following commands with mongosh.

```
> var book = db.books.findOne({title:'Good book'})
> var dbRef = book.publishers[0]
> dbRef
DBRef("publishers", ObjectId("..."))
```

According to the link below, I think I can access $id and $ref of the dbRef object, but I got empty lines. How can I access $id and $ref with mongosh?

```
> dbRef.$id 
  // empty line

> dbRef.$ref
  // empty line

> dbRef.collection
publishers

> JSON.stringify(dbRef)
{"$ref":"publishers","$id":"..."}
```

[How to show data from 2 collections in Mongodb with DBRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055609/how-to-show-data-from-2-collections-in-mongodb-with-dbref)

***UPDATE***

For newer version of mongosh,

```
> dbRef.oid
ObjectId("...")
> dbRef.collection
publishers
```

For older version of mongosh,

```
> dbRef.toJSON().$id
ObjectId("...")

> dbRef.toJSON().$ref
publishers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBRef is a separate data type: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/DBRef.html

new DBRef(namespace, oid, db)

| Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| namespace | string | the collection name |
| oid | ObjectID | the reference ObjectID |
| db | string | optional db name, if omitted the reference is local to the current db |

Try `dbRef.oid`

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working for mongosh. I do find out way to access $id now.

Comment: @Marv are you sure? In my `mongosh 1.6.0` it works fine

Comment: I see, I am using 1.4.0, maybe this is the reason. I will try the never version.

Comment: dbRef.oid is working for mongosh 1.6.0. I will accept your answer, thanks!